# IceCandidate connected not getting chrome new update

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, kurento

Unable to reach **IceConnectionState "completed"** in new chrome browser  **"Version 52.0.2743.116 m"** only getting **IceConnectionState "checking"**, but same code working fine with chrome browser **Version 51.0.2704.103 m** media is flowing in this version.

I'm using kurento media server 6.0 and libnice version 0.1.13. Is this is the problem of kurento do I need to update anything ? (Server is returning SDP and IceCandidate in both browser version)

Comment: If the answer from Philipp helped you (which I'm sure it did), you should accept it as valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 52 changed the DTLS handshake (see [the release notes](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/bDfxOA8XiJI/R6QOrQDMBgAJ)) which might cause this if the servers ssl lib is too old.

Comment: I'm not using any SSL certificate for kurento server. A nodejs server is used to exchange SDP and Icecandidates between client and kurento server. SSL certificate is used for that nodejs server and both nodejs server and kurento server are running on the same machine. Now, do I need use SSL for kurento server also?

Comment: this is about the dtls-webrtc exchange done over udp. Kurento might not require you to set a certificate but encryption is required by chrome for webrtc data so this should be there.

Comment: Again I've got the same problem Unable to reach IceConnectionState "completed". After using SSL certificate it starts working fine but now again I'm stuck with the same problem. (Right now chrome browser version is Version 53.0.2785.116 m)